# How to Link Multiple Classes Together Efficiently

Tags: python, class

Background:
I have been working on a game in Python, and in order to keep everything clean, organized and in a pythonic way, I have a folder containing multiple python files, each containing one big class, for example "MapEngine" or "NPCEngine".

From main.py, I am loading each class from each file and "glueing everything together with a "Game" class, such as:

```
from folder import *

class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.MapEngine ＝ MapEngine.MapEngine()
        ...

    def loop(self):
        ...
```

Since classes such as "CollisionEngine" requires data from other classes such as, "MapEngine", I usually assign some variables in the former (i.e. CollisionEngine) to the latter (i.e MapEngine), in order to use MapEngine's loaded map data or functions:

```
class CollisionEngine:

    def __init__(self, MapClass, ...):
        self.MapEngine ＝ MapClass
```

**Problem**: 
Well, since many classes have to be linked to others, it became hard after a while to figure out which class to load first in order to assign variables. Furthermore, classes like "EventEngine" need to have access to every other class. My code became hard to read, and I have trouble when 2 classes are equally important to each other.

**Question**:
I have heard of class inheritance, but I do not think it can be applied here because each class is very different as in its function. Therefore, is there a way to beautifully link every class together, as if it was all part of one big class? In other words, is there a way to refer to variables from other classes, from within a class?

(My thoughts: Perhaps, I can write a class called "Request", and it will act as a top level class manager. Although, I think I will have to use functions such as exec() or eval(), which are not efficient and are somewhat dangerous.)

This is my first post, I've tried to be as explicit as possible, please ask me for clarification, & thank you for your reply!

Comment: Assuming that the coupling is necessary, and it's just verbose to wire up all the dependencies it may be worth it to pull in [a dependency injection framework like pinject](https://github.com/google/pinject)

Comment: I find this a little hard to understand. Maybe an image can help?

Comment: You don't need to have a class (MapClass) stored as a variable of another class (CollisionEngine in your example), nor do you need to import it, in order to access the variables and methods of MapClass. Read up on *ducktyping*, if your CollisionEngine has a method `collisionOnCoords(map, x, y)` you could assume (or check ;)) that the `map` object is of type MapClass, and you can access MapClass's methods and variables that way. In other words; store an instance of MapClass, not the actual class.

Comment: If that's not it, then it would help if you expanded your description of the actual problem. You definitely shouldn't have to resort to `exec()` or `eval()` by the way.

Comment: @alKid In simple words, from each of my classes, I assign different variables to link to previously loaded classes, and it s messy.

Comment: @Junuxx, and Sean, thank you for your input, I will looking into those. I will do some tests later, and hopefully have an answer later on. Afterall, programming is sometimes a game of trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after many tries, I have figured out a (sketchy) way of solving my problem. Of course, as eddiewould suggested, I will have a better organization and multiple layers for my code, but if one would like to have multiple classes all linked together, simply include a variable to the main class (that called every class) to every class. I believe that a code snippet will explain it better:

```
main.py
engine_folder
----> engine_1.py
----> engine_2.py
```

in main.py, engine_1 and engine_2 are loaded:

```
from engine_folder import engine_1, engine_2

class game:

  def __init__(self):
      self.engine_1 = engine_1.engine(self, ...)
      self.engine_2 = engine_2.engine(self, ...)
      #where engine_1.engine and engine_2.engine are
      #two classes that need to transfer data between
      #each other

  def run(self):
      self.engine_1.run()
      self.engine_2.run()
```

Notice how engine_1.engine's first argument is self, which refers to the top level class which called this class. Now, in engine_1, if we would want to print a variable from engine_2, the class would look similar to this:

```
class engine:

  def __init__(self, top_level_class, ...):
      self.top_level_class = top_level_class

  def run(self):
      print self.top_level_class.engine_2.random_var
```

This is very beautiful (besides the fact that print self.top_level_class.engine_2.random_var is very long), but compared to something like:

```
class EventEngine:

  def __init__(self, Camera_Class, Map_Class, Character_Class, Skill_Class,
               Interface_Class, Sprite_Class, Dialog_Class, Game_Class,
               Item_Class):
      self.ItemEngine = Item_Class
      self.GameEngine = Game_Class
      self.DialogEngine = Dialog_Class
      self.SpriteEngine = Sprite_Class
      self.SkillEngine = Skill_Class
      self.CameraEngine = Camera_Class
      self.MapEngine = Map_Class
      self.CharacterEngine = Character_Class
      self.IEngine = Interface_Class
```

The new version:

```
class EventEngine:
  def __init__(self, top_level_class):
      self.top = top_level_class
      #a var from Map_Class can be called as such:
      #self.top.MapEngine.map[0][1]
      #and I can call variables from every class, not only those I 
      #have loaded like before
```

is much better and much cleaner.

Comment: It really does sound like your project would benefit from dependency injection (i.e. inversion of control) - suggest you have a read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider separating your project into layers - that should help you keep things more organised and make the imports more natural.

The principle is that lower layers of your code "cake" shouldn't depend on (read: import) upper layers of your code.

For example you might have a foundation layer which contains common data structures, util classes and algorithms that are used in lots of your code at various layers.

Then you might have a model layer which depends on the foundation layer (i.e. data structures/utils/algorithms) but nothing else. The model layer provides models of objects within the domain.

You might then have a game layer which depends on the model layer (so it would be quite reasonable for modules in your game layer to import things from the model layer, but not vice versa).