# Python - Connect two classes using a new kinda of "connector" class (Design Patterns)

Tags: python, class

I want to connect my two high-level classes Foo and Bar together. My kind of solution is to create a new class which serves as a "connector" to these two classes. I don't want to input methods for connecting inside my two high-level classes because I want to keep them intact in new versions of the problem. Is that a right way to think about Object-oriented planning and Desing patters or am I doing it completely wrong? Should I just inherit one class from the other and do a connect method to one of the two (Foo, Bar)?

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.foo = attr


class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.bar = attr


class Connect(object):

    def connect(self, first, second):
        do some connection between first and second class ()


def main():
    first = Foo(10)
    second = Bar(15)

    connector = Connect()
    connector.connect(first, second)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The question is: what do you want to do with the two classes together?

Comment: Why do you want to connect them? Are you looking for [multiple inheritance](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_multiple_inheritance.php)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Link Multiple Classes Together Efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623425/how-to-link-multiple-classes-together-efficiently)

Comment: Lets say I want to grab some stuff from the first class and store them to the second one that is my main database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you're looking for the [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). It's valid - you make your two instances components of a higher-level data structure and do whatever your "connecting" logic is there.

Important question here: what exactly does "connecting" mean for you? What are you looking to do, concretely?

---

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS**

You could structure it something like this (which is pretty much what you've got, just using concrete names):

```
class PersistenceService:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config
        ...

    def persist(storage_department, products)
        # Copy storage items to DB


storage_department = StorageDepartment(...)
products = ProductList(...) # Or, just python list of products

persistence_service = PersistenceService(<some config>)
persistence_service.persist(storage_department, products)
```

Really there isn't one single correct way of structuring these things. In Python, methods are objects themselves, so you technically don't even *need* to have your "connector" logic in a class. You could just have a `persist(...)` method.

Comment: Like if there is a database - client connection. So yeah the composite pattern is the thing I am looking for here. But in Python, this program I wrote above is it well designed? I am kinda newbie in OOP so that's why I am asking this. Thank you for the answer

Comment: To be more clear. Let's say the first class is the storage department and the second class is the new products coming that needs to be stored in the storage department. Something like that. And I am asking in python is this the right way to implement Desing patterns like the composite pattern?

Comment: Yeah what you have is fine, assuming you use clearly understandable method/class names. Note that the functionality you're implementing is a reusable service, so "Connector" its really more an example of a service object than a composite object. I've updated my answer with some example code.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. This question came to me after reading about UML, efficient design and design patterns and I wanted the opinion of a more experienced developer since I am kinda newbie into OOP. Thank you again

Comment: No problem. Design patterns are a pretty big area, and there's usually more than one good way of doing something. Best of luck with your learning!